# jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: php, jquery

```
$.post("#", params).then(function (response) {
    if (obj['error'] != 1) {
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < response['data'].length; i++) {
            console.log('data' + i, response['data'][i]);
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td>' + response['data'][i]['wallet_type'] + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + response['data'][i]['balance'] + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + response['data'][i]['wallet_address'] + '</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
        }
    }
});
```

I found

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

in the console for that i cannot able to display my result.

Comment: The Error message is clear : you do `response['data'].length` and `response['data']` is undefined

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Clearly, `response['data']` is `undefined`. Only you can see why that is, using the debugger built into your browser to examine the `response` variable's contents, etc.

Comment: @Andreas,
It's a javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check your response array in console something missing in your response.i think your response array does not set.
ex. `console.log(response);`

```
<script>
    var response={"data":[{"id":556,"user_id":333,"email":"alokkr@dispostable.com","name":"alokkr@dispostable.com","wallet_id":"5ab7dfaa39062807cc3d0659a5ee9634","wallet_address":"QNqpGLNDhsCLWsqbz4joJHnh7QBQYhWQhz","wallet_type":"ltc","balance":0,"is_custom":false,"is_test":"0","created":"2018-03-25T17:44:50","updated":null},],"error":0,"msg":[]}
    //console.log(response['data'].length);        
    var html='';
    for (var i = 0; i < response['data'].length; i++) {
    console.log('data' + i, response['data'][i]);
    html += "<table border='1'>";
    html += "<tr>";

    html += '<td>' + response['data'][i]['wallet_type'] + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + response['data'][i]['balance'] + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + response['data'][i]['wallet_address'] + '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    html += '</table>';
    }
    document.write(html);
 </script>
```

Comment: You should also use ex.   document.write(response);

Comment: I get the proper response in console, the main problem is that when i use to print the result in  html <td> tag. I don't get any response there.!

Comment: Please give me result of the response array

Comment: {"data":[{"id":556,"user_id":333,"email":"alokkr@dispostable.com","name":"alokkr@dispostable.com","wallet_id":"5ab7dfaa39062807cc3d0659a5ee9634","wallet_address":"QNqpGLNDhsCLWsqbz4joJHnh7QBQYhWQhz","wallet_type":"ltc","balance":0,"is_custom":false,"is_test":"0","created":"2018-03-25T17:44:50","updated":null},],"error":0,"msg":[]}

Comment: please use html += "<table border='1'>";

Comment: document.write(html);